# sharing rule -criteria sharing rule row limit

Tags: settings, sharing

I have an issue ,while creating a criteria based sharing rule,I have more than 50 criteria I need to add but after adding 25 rows,for me add row option is getting disabled,I am not able to add more than 25 criteria based sharing rule,Can anyone please help me with this issue. Please find the attached screenshot.

Thanks in advance

I need some sort of solution how to add more rows in criteria based sharing rule.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.